# How to duplicate input into outputs with jq?

Tags: unix, jq

I'm trying to adapt the following snippet:

```
echo '{"a":{"value":"b"}, "c":{"value":"d"}}' \
    | jq -r '. as $in | keys[] | [$in[.].value | tostring + " 1"] | @tsv'
b 1
d 1
```

to output:

```
b 1
b 2
d 1
d 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following adaptation produces the desired output:

```
echo '{"a":{"value":"b"}, "c":{"value":"d"}}' |
  jq -r '
    def addindex(start;lessthan): 
      range(start;lessthan) as $i | "\(.) \($i)";
    . as $in
    | keys[]
    | $in[.].value
    | addindex(1;3)'
```

Note that `keys` emits the key names after they have been sorted, whereas `keys_unsorted` retains the ordering.

Comment: Could `. as $in
    | keys[]
    | $in[.].value` be reduced as just `recurse|scalars`. Is it recommended to do that? Atleast for the given input where there are no parent level scalars?

Comment: @Inian - I've just adapted the given answer as it's unclear what is really wanted, but note that the Q uses `keys`, not `keys_unsorted`.